# Overlapping elements in linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

Here I am trying to display holidays and leave request image side by side, vertically below employee info and leave info image. But somehow the holidays and leave request images are not displayed and seems to have been overlapped. How do I rectify this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
        android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
            android:src="@drawable/employee_info"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_info"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
            android:src="@drawable/holidays"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_request"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `layout_weight` on image views inside horizontal linear layout and set `layout_height` of linear layouts to `wrap_content`. Dont forget to change `layout_width` to `0dp`. And put whole layout in `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
            android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
                android:src="@drawable/employee_info"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
                android:src="@drawable/leave_info"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
                android:src="@drawable/holidays"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
                android:src="@drawable/leave_request"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **LinearLayout** height of your images to **wrap_content**.

Try this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
        android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> <!-- Changes here -->

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
            android:src="@drawable/employee_info"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_info"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> <!-- Changes here -->

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
            android:src="@drawable/holidays"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_request"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two LinearLayouts of employee info and holidays in a container layout and set the width of each one of them to `android:layout_width="0dp"` and the weight to `android:layout_weight="0.5"`, So the result will be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
                android:src="@drawable/employee_info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/leave_info" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
                android:src="@drawable/holidays" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/leave_request" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**p.s.** if you want the employee info and holidays logos to be *under each other* not *side-by-side* just change the `container` layout orientation to `vertical`.